# How do you configure Qt Creator to use both Qt4 and Qt5?

Tags: qt-creator

I download Qt Creator 2.7.0 (Based on Qt 5.0.2 (64 bit)).
This seems to compile everything with Qt5.

I know you can download the Qt4 SDK, but then how can i configure projects to use Qt4 instead if I need to? Please provide detailed instructions. I'm on Ubuntu and not using any repository supplied Qt tools/libraries.

Answer (score 8):

Answer: You download Qt4, compile it (if necessary) then in the menu Tools->Options->Build & Run->Qt Versions, you add Qt4 manually similar to the Qt5 config. You just need the path to the qmake file. Then go to the Kits tab in the same Options box, and add a manual Qt 4 Kit. You can change the Kit available to your app via the Projects tile and the Add Kit button. Add the Qt4 kit, remove the Qt5 kit, rebuild all. Simple.

ref: http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-targets.html

Comment: Hi, I have followed all this steps, but despite I add the qt4 kit, the project still takes the qt5 include paths. Any suggestions? Did you change anything else?

Comment: No sorry. I just moved to the newer Qt5 :)